# Mockito 2 - SpringBoot 1.5.11.RELEASE - Could not initialize class org.mockito.Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to mock the `final class` which is available in our company's internal library using Mockito 2.18.3 framework, unfortunately we don't have access to change the code in the library. But whenever I run I get below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.Mockito

at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:55)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:50)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:319)
```

This is my dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public class JwtTokenTest {
   @Autowired
   private class JwtValidatorService jwtValidatorService;

   @Mock
   private JwtTokenDetails jwtTokenDetails;

   @Test
   public void jwtGenerateTest() {
      //Code to test JWT generation
   }
}
```

Also as per this link: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable  I have created `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file with contents: `mock-maker-inline`.

I tried searching in other Stackoverflow posts and Google, but still not solution. Can anyone kindly help me in this? Looks like I am missing something, but failed to identify it. Since I don't have much expertise in Mockito, tried to use powermock but it is posing different challenges in downloading dependencies in company's network.

Please let me know if I need to add more code or more details.

Comment: how are you running tests?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDE, just right click and run the test class.

Comment: hmm did you try to refresh your maven/gradle project clean build?

Comment: Yes I did, I cleared target folder, run with mvn clean install -U

Comment: ok.. I'd suggest you to look into the run configurations of your test. I can say of eclipse : test->right click->run->run configurations. Then look at the dependecies present there. Most probably your actual dependencies might not be matching those.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 1.5.11 is compatible with Mockito 1.x. Specifically, it uses 1.10.19. Rather than overriding the version of Mockito to a new major version, you should let Spring Boot's dependency management specify the version. Doing so will ensure that you use a compatible version. If Mockito 1.10 doesn't meet your needs, you'll need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Basically I want to mock final class from internal library. It means it is not possible in Spring Boot 1.5.11 ?

Comment: It's hard to say for certain without some more information. Your question doesn't show why `org.mockito.Mockito` could not be initialized. Can you update it to include all of the relevant log output or, even better, a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Since version 1.5.2.RELEASE of spring boot and 2.0.3.RELEASE ([and possibly earlier](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8217)), spring boot supports Mockito Version 2.X. see [commit for README file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d42a54e8802f734676b30805c88c8b19eb44e0e6)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot uses Mockito 1.x by **default**. However, **it's possible to override it** with Mockito 2.x, as Spring Boot can also use it without any problems (see [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d42a54e8802f734676b30805c88c8b19eb44e0e6)).

To do so, just add this modification to your POM file properties:

```
<properties>
    <mockito.version>2.18.3</mockito.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: That's not correct. Overriding version to Mockito 2.X with Spring boot 1.5 causes problems. My unit tests run correctly but integration tests fail.